# C++ find out if a variable is a reference or pointer

Tags: c++, macros

I have a macro in the *catch* section of code, say

```
#define CATCH( doSomething )           \
    catch (MyException& e)             \
    {                                  \
        try                            \
        {                              \
            doSomething;               \
        }                              \
    }                                  \
    catch (MyException* e)             \
    {                                  \
        try                            \
        {                              \
            doSomething;               \
        }                              \
    }
```

and in the *doSomething* section I need to get to the contents of an exception, is there a way to do this? 
Some function *isPointer* that can be used like this:

```
try
{
    THROW(new MyException());
}
CATCH(                                 \
    if( isPointer(e) )                 \
    {                                  \
        std::cout << (*e).toString();  \
    }                                  \
    else                               \
    {                                  \
        std::cout << e.toString();     \
    }                                  \
)
```

Comment: You can do this using template dispatch

Comment: Staring too long at the lines of backslashes creates a strange optical illusion... Anyway, you'd probably be much, much better off by just making sure that you always throw a stack-allocated value and catch it by reference. There is nothing to gain by using `new` here; catching by reference allows you to get polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: In C++11 you can use type traits to check for this. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types. Also remember that when catching a pointer, remember to `delete` it!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Unfortunately, when catching a pointer, there's no way to know whether or not you should delete it; one lunatic could `throw new MyException` while another could `throw &static_exception`. You really shouldn't be throwing pointers in the first place.

Comment: of course there was `delete` in CATCH macro, it was me too lazy to write down everything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use overloading to possibly dereference the argument:

```
template<class T>
T& deref(T* p) { return *p; }

template<class T>
T& deref(T& r) { return r; }
```

And use that:

```
CATCH(                                 \
    std::cout << deref(e).toString();  \
)
```

Though I have to admit I see *no* reason to dynamically allocate exception objects.

Comment: +1 for 'no reason to dynamically allocate exception objects'.

Comment: why those "\" ? even if you don't use them it will work, c++ skips ws in code :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Those were part of the original macro.

Comment: I'd +1 for 'no reason to dynamically allocate' too =)
and this way is exactly what does a trick in this case, thank you.